# How could node.js server access the ajax request's data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Below are my Server's code

```
/* GET tone. */
router.post('/tone', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("what is the body" + req.body.data);
  tone_analyzer.tone({ text: req.body.data }, function(err, tone) {
    console.log(req.body.data);
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2));
    }
    console.log(req);
  });
});
```

My Ajax's call in the html page.

```
function toneAnalysis(info){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/tone',
    type: 'POST',
    data: info,
    success: function(res) {
      console.log("testing " + info);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
      console.log(status);
    }
  })
```

The server could not retrieve the `req.body.data`. When I tried to console log it, it always prints undefined. Could any one help me out with this? Thank you.

Update:
[The printed req.body after I used body parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iMTW.png)

Comment: It should just be req.body. Log that out and see if it's defined. You may need to use body-parser.

Comment: Second the comment that you may need body parser, also look at typeof(req.data) if it === 'string' then you may need to JSON parse it.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer above mentioned you can use [BodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and you can download it and install it using npm like so:

```
# npm install bodyparser --save
```

Then returning to your **$.ajax** call, you are sending some data represented in the **data** object, so using the **BodyParser** you can simply have an access to the sent object, because **BodyParser** add another object to the **req** nodejs object and it's called **body**, so if you want to access to all sent items using **BodyParser** you will probably going to do it like so :

```
  const app = require('express')();
  let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

  // add a new middleware to your application with the help of BodyParser
  // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  // parse application/json
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  //Configure the route
  router.post('/tone', (req, res, next) => {
     console.log("what is the body" + req.body.data);
     tone_analyzer.tone({ text: req.body.data}, (err, tone) => {
        console.log(req.body.data);
        if (err){
           console.log(err);
        }
        else{
           res.send(JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2));
        }
        console.log(req);
     });
   });
```

Now using BodyParser, things can get really easy when you handle your XHR or HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

your request body will be in req.body

if it is json you can use

```
    let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/tone', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("what is the body" + req.body);
     tone_analyzer.tone({ text: req.body},
    function(err, tone) { 
     // your code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your server configuration?

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

This allows you to parse JSON requests.

Comment: I have this line on my app.js

Comment: What about your package.json file do you have bodyparser within it ? @estherfang

Comment: @HoussemYahiaoui yeah,  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }

Comment: @estherfang this code :  if you are using this line of code app.use(express.bodyParser())   it won't work and it's is actually pretty old, because express is not bundled with connectJS  therefore simply require the body parser and see what i answered above in my proposed answer,